# Как перемножить некоторое количество чисел внутри числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, математика

Функция принимает число **N**, и должна вернуть количество раз, которое вы должны умножить цифры между собой **N**, пока не получится одна цифра.

---

Пример:

```
9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126, 1*2*6 = 12,  1*2 = 2
```

Мой код работает только в при вызове с двухзначным числом.

```
def persistence(n):
    count = 0
    while len(str(n)) > 1:
        n=int(str(n)[0])*int(str(n)[1])
        count+=1
    return count
   
print(persistence(999))
```

Как реализовать для неограниченного кол-ва чисел?
Если можно, то интересует именно через цикл **while**

Comment: добавьте еще один цикл - по цифрам числа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться функцией reduce и преобразованием числа в строку цифр

```
from functools import reduce

def persistence(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 9:
        n = reduce(lambda x, y: x*int(y), str(n), 1)
        count += 1
    return count

print(persistence(999))
```

Comment: А если будет цифра 0 ?

Comment: будет ответ 0 - не надо действий

Comment: Я имел ввиду 909 -> 9 *9 -> 81 -> 8*1 -> 8 Моё ощущение, что это не корректное поведение функции :)

Comment: а что должна вернуть при получении от 0 до 9? чем 0 отличается от 5, скажем?

Comment: Я поправил комментарий

Comment: не вижу противоречий: 101 - один раз, получили односимвольное число

Comment: А тогда в числе 909 сколько умножений

Comment: всего одно, как и в 101

Comment: Ваш ответ очень хорош, но не всегда корректно отрабатывает.
При числе например 25 будет 2 итерации, а в данном случае будет учтена только одна.
т.е должно быть 25 => 2*5, потом 10 =>1*0 и только потом == 1
в данном коде итерация с десяткой не учлась

Comment: Поправил на > 9

Answer (score 0):

Цифры числа можно складывать в list, для этого можно написать отдельную функцию. А потом пробегать циклом по цифрам и умножать.

```
# Функция возвращает list из цифр числа
def digits(n):
    digs =[]
    while n != 0:
        digs.append(n % 10)
        n = n // 10
    return digs

def persistence(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 9:
        digs = digits(n)
        mul = 1
        # Здесь пробежимся циклом по цифрам и перемножим их
        for digit in digs:
            mul = mul * digit
        n = mul
        print('*'.join(map(str, digs)) + '=' + str(mul))
        count+=1
    return count
   
print(persistence(999))
```

Comment: `for digit in str(n): mul *= int(digit)`

Comment: @splash58, ну зачем строки в математических задачах... `n = reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, digs)`

Comment: ваш ответ, вам и решать -я бы не стал городить для этого функцию

Answer (score 0):

Что делать если будет цифра "0" - я буду её пропускать

```
def persistence(n):
    
    def per(n, count):
        newc = 1
        if n < 10: 
            return (n, count)

        while n > 10:
            i = n % 10
            if i > 0 :
                print(f'{n % 10} * ', end='')
                newc *= n % 10
                count += 1
            n = n // 10
        
        print(f'{n}')
        return per(newc * n, count)

    (n,c) = per(n, 0)
    return c
   
print(f'Answer: {persistence(999)}')

9 * 9 * 9
9 * 2 * 7
6 * 2 * 1
2 * 1
Answer: 7

print(f'Answer: {persistence(909)}')

9 * 9
1 * 8
Answer: 2
```

Comment: **Функция принимает число N, и должна вернуть количество раз,** а не отладочные красоты :)